# How to encode challenge password into certificate request

Tags: python, c, linux, openssl

I am using linux version openssl req to generate a csr with challenge password, everything goes fine, except it can not print this attribute:

```
# openssl req -new -key private.key -out server.csr 
# openssl req -in server.csr -noout -text
  Certificate Request: ...
         Attributes:
             challengePassword        :unable to print attribute ...
```

I tested with OpenSSL 1.0.1j in fedora, and OpenSSL 1.0.1 in ubuntu, both can not write challengePassword into csr file.

But if I use windows version, it can work:

```
# openssl req -in test.csr -noout -text
  Certificate Request:
  ...
        Attributes:
            challengePassword        :00F7FC7937B5366F2231AC891472998C
```

...
I am using the 64bit openssl from the [SCEP tool](http://secadmins.com/?dl_id=9):

Then I searched openssl document, and found this sentence:

> attributes
>
> this specifies the section containing any request attributes: its
>   format is the same as distinguished_name. Typically these may contain
>   the
>   **challengePassword** or unstructuredName types. **They are currently ignored by OpenSSL's request signing utilities but some CAs might want
>   them**.

Yes, some CAs might want them. I am using NDES windows 2008 r2, it needs challenge password, it looks like it can not be generated by openssl req application, can I use openssl C API or python/perl? Or do I need to fix the openssl code?

I also asked this question on the sscep issue list, they told me I need to encode challenge password to BMPString. But I don't know how to encode it. Can someone give me guide?

Comment: My topic is a little misleading. It should be "how to encode challenge password into certificate request".

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer my question by myself.

To enable challenge password attribute in the CSR, we need to write ASN printable string, but the openssl req utility by default writes MBSTRING_ASC string, so it always return ":unable to print attribute ..."

Here is the C code sample:

Convert MBSTRING_ASC string to ASN1_PRINTABLESTRING:

```
ASN1_STRING *tmp_os = M_ASN1_PRINTABLESTRING_new();
tmp_os->type = V_ASN1_PRINTABLESTRING;
int password_length = strlen(challenge_password);
ASN1_STRING_set(tmp_os, (const unsigned char *)challenge_password, password_length);
```

Add attributes to the request:

```
X509_REQ_add1_attr_by_NID(req, NID_pkcs9_challengePassword, tmp_os->type, tmp_os->data, password_length);
```